# C# parent-child round trip Close() not working properly but Hide() does

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a C# console/winforms desktop app.  It monitors some local drive properties and displays a status message on a user defined schedule via Task Scheduler.  Multiple schedules can be saved by the user.  Below are the actions taken to select/activate a particular saved schedule (the screenshots are sized at 50% and consolidated into a single graphic):

- Screenshot A: click on “Change Active” button to call child form
- Screenshot B: select a schedule from Combobox and click Activate
  Selected Schedule which closes the child form, passing the selected
  schedule for processing.
- Screenshot C – result using Close()method:
  The schedule definition screen is populated with the selected
  schedule’s details including (if needed) calling a different child
  form BUT the select active schedule form in not actually closing
  before the parent form starts the processing for populating the data; Child1 only closes after Child2 is closed by clicking Save or Cancel.
- Screenshot D – result using Hide()method: working as intended
  [image]

Relevant code (I think)

```
public interface IselectSchedule
{
    void SelectSchedule(string sName);
}
/// Parent form
public partial class DefineSched : Form, IDates, IDoWs, IselectSchedule
{
/// calling Child1
    private void ChangeActvLBLasBTN_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetActvSchedule callSetActvSched = new SetActvSchedule(this);
        callSetActvSched.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        callSetActvSched.Location = new Point(this.Left + 45, this.Top + 25);
        callSetActvSched.ShowDialog();
    }
}
/// Child1 form
public partial class SetActvSchedule : Form
{
    IselectSchedule _callingForm;
    public SetActvSchedule(IselectSchedule caller)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _callingForm = caller;
    }
    /// form content
    private void SaveBTN_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close(); // not achieving my objective but Hide does
        _callingForm.SelectSchedule(_sname);
    }
}
/// back in Parent form
    public void SelectSchedule(string sName)
    {
        _sName = sName;
        bool useDB = false;
        SetActvDisplay(useDB);
        EditSaved(useDB);
    }
    private void EditSaved(bool useDB)
    {
        /// populate parent form data & call Child2
        SelectDoW callSelectDoWs = new SelectDoW(this, det, det2);
        callSelectDoWs.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        callSelectDoWs.ShowDialog(owner: this);
        /// ready for editing
```

I’ve researched/understand the Hide vs Close decision and think Close  is appropriate here.  My question is since Close() precedes returning to the parent form why isn’t that action completed before the parent form starts processing the passed info?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: I think the problem starts with doing it in the form you are closing/hiding. Needing the parent here feels awkward. Why not just do it after ShowDialog from the calling form? In the past i often used my own overrides of ShowDialog to return something in the "OK" case. The answer to the hide/close question. Close() is a message to the system to close the form when the system processes messages and between you call to close and your call to the parent form there is no involvement of the system that processes messages.

Comment: Most of your screenshots appear to be missing.

Comment: Usually the problem of UI not updating as you expect is because you're doing too much work on the UI thread rather than pushing that work off onto other threads and leaving the UI thread free to process messages.

Comment: @Ralf Thank you.  I presume you mean _callSetActvSched.ShowDialog(); _callSetActvSched.Close(); that doesn't work since Child1 doesn't close at all even after Child2 closes; At Westley the screenshots are sized at 50% and consolidated into a single graphic

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever OK - thanks.  I was beginning to suspect this might be a Thread related issue.  I'm a C# novice and my only multi-Threading used a backgroundworker which I don't think is appropriate here.  I'll start researching utilizing another Thread but any additional advice will be appreciated

Comment: Putting heavy lifting away from the main thread is mostly a good idea. I don't think it will help here. I also think you haven't seen all the problems attached to your approach yet. You show the form as modal (ShowDialog). At the spot where you are trying to hide/close it you might get it visually away from the desktop but you will still be in the modal context of that form. And while you in that modal context you are trying to open a different modal form (with a different parent as the current modal form).

Comment: That calls for additional trouble. I can just repeat myself. You should try to get the call to SelectSchedule after the form really closed. And that is only after ShowDialog for the SetActvSchedule form has ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I believe I nearly got the multi-thread approach suggested above to work I ran into a cross-Threading error I couldn’t resolve.  Upon further consideration I may have been pursuing an unnecessarily complicated solution to achieve a very simple objective; present the user with some options and act on their selection.

The simple solution utilizes a public static field in the parent form that is set in the child form after which the child is cleanly closed and control returns to the parent form:

```
/// Parent form
public partial class DefineSched : Form
{
    public static string _sName;

    /// calling Child
    private void ChangeActvBTN_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetActvSchedule callSetActvSched = new SetActvSchedule();
        callSetActvSched.ShowDialog();
        ActvSchedOptions();
    }
}
/// Child1 form
public partial class SetActvSchedule : Form
{
    private void SaveBTN_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DefineSched._sName = _sname;
        this.Close();
    }
}
/// back in Parent form
    ActvSchedOptions()
    {
        /// series of conditional statements
```

This approach circumvents the need for the Interface and avoids overloading the UI thread.  I suspect it’ll not be considered a particularly elegant solution but it has one redeeming virtue: it works flawlessly for the task at hand.